# How find the Name in multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post

Is there a way to get the names of the form fields from `$_POST` ?

I know I can get the values with `$_POST['foo']`, but how do I get the list of names (not sure what they are called).

Any help is great.

Comment: It is called a *key*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST` is an associative array. Use `array_keys` to get the keys of the array.

```
$names = array_keys($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple as that

```
print_r($_POST);
```

> print_r — Prints human-readable information about a variable

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

An array consists of array key and value.

```
$array = array('color1' => 'red','color2' => 'blue', 'color3' => 'green');
```

to get the key values use

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
print_r($keys);
```